# subdomain for each user using php

Tags: php

I own a website that gives every registered user a dedicated space like this:\

```
www.mywebpage.com/user1
www.mywebpage.com/user2
www.mywebpage.com/user3
```

Inside this path, the user has his mini-website.

I'd like to give my users not a path within my domain, but a second-level domain like this:

```
user1.mywebpage.com
user2.mywebpage.com
user3.mywebpage.com
```

A lot of websites do this, but I can't figure out how to get it!

Comment: This question is way too broad for this site, but you’ll need (at a base level) a wildcard DNS record to point to a server which is configured to return a response based on the requested subdomain. For any additional assistance beyond that you’ll need to  edit your question to ask something a bit more specific about code you’ve already written (we don’t design end-to-end systems for you here, especially without any discernible attempt on your part). [ask]

Comment: How is this a php question?  The enabling tech would be a wildcard DNS entry for the mywebpage.com domain of *.mywebpage.com.  How to actually handle the vhost would depend on your webserving infrastructure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. You could ask on [webmasters.se], but check their help centre before posting.

Comment: If someone can't point to a canonical response after so many years, is it really a duplicate? Shouldn't SO have a "dynamic vhost" answer worthy of relinking here?

Comment: In other words, it's a quintessential programming issue (dynamic path resolution based on dns decomposition) masquerading as a "webmaster" problem. Can't we link to something useful depicting how to think about this issue without going out to the webmaster community?